# outlook 2007 addin : How to remove particular userproperty of mailItem

Tags: c#, outlook-2007

I am developing utility application in Outlook 2007

I am able to add User property for Particular mailItem

```
<i>
  myMailItem.UserProperties.Add("ParentMailRecipients",     Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText,true, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
            myMailItem.UserProperties["ParentMailRecipients"].Value = SavedMailItem.To + ";" + SavedMailItem.CC;
            myMailItem.Save();
 </i>
```

After a period of time  I need to delete the particular User property.

User Property has the method for removing the user property(Remove(int))

I dont know How to find the index of particular User property and Delete it. Please help me to find solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can search retrieve the UserProperty from the UserProperties collection  using property name and once you have the UserProperty Object, call Delete method on that.

```
UserProperty up = myMailItem.UserProperties["ParentMailRecipients"];
if(up != null)
    up.Delete();
```