# How to remove a specific ItemProperty from AppointmentItem.ItemProperties

Tags: outlook, vsto

I use the following method to a new OutlookUserProperty to an AppointmentItem:

```
MyID = (Outlook.UserProperty)myAppointment.ItemProperties.Add("MyID", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, 1);
```

... later I want to remove exactly this "MyID" from the ItemProperties collection.
Obviously I can only remove an item from the ItemProperties collection using the

```
myAppointment.ItemProperties.Remove(index).`
```

Unfortunately I don't know the index of the element "MyID", and I cannot find any method for retrieving the index of "MyID".

Answer (score 1):

Use `PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperty`.

To figure out the DASL property name, take a look at the item with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button, select the property, look at the DASL property editor).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use UserProperty.Delete to delete your ItemProperty.

```
UserProperty up = myMailItem.UserProperties["ParentMailRecipients"];
if(up != null)
  up.Delete();
```

More info about: [UserProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/userproperty-delete-method-outlook)

Reference: [outlook 2007 addin : How to remove particular userproperty of mailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240284/outlook-2007-addin-how-to-remove-particular-userproperty-of-mailitem)

Hope it works for you.