# How to remove UserProperty with Outlook Interop?

Tags: c#, outlook, com

I've run the following code to add a particular UserProperty of type `olText`:

```
mailItem.UserProperties.Add(Name: "MyProperty", Type: OlUserPropertyType.olText);
```

I decided I wanted to use integer for the type instead, and changed my code to:

```
mailItem.UserProperties.Add(Name: "MyProperty", Type: OlUserPropertyType.olInteger);
```

This, however, gives me a `COMException` stating that the property name already exists, but with a different type. I was not even aware that user properties would persist after shutting down my application. Now I can't seem to get rid of it!

I've tried as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8241185/12676067), but when I try to retrieve the `UserProperty` with `mailItem.UserProperties["MyProperty"]` I get `null`.

How can I get completely rid of the user properties that I've added? How do I even see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot keep in the same name and change the property type - once a named MAPI property is used with a particular type, the store provider remembers it.

You'd need to change the property name.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Can you elaborate what you mean by "store provider"? Can I somehow obtain a list of properties that the store provider has "remembered"?

Comment: Store provider is what actually stores your messages - it is, for example, the PST provider or MSEMS (OST and online Exchange stores). 
You can see the list in OutlookSpy: click IMessage (or IMAPIFolder or IMsgStore) and click GetNamesFromIDs

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UserProperties.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.find) method which locates and returns a `UserProperty` object for the requested property name, if it exists. Only if it is found you can call the `Delete` method to remove the existing declaration add a new one with a new property type.